# Files appearing to never load on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

When trying to launch a web game through safari on an iPhone (unsure if this also affects iPads, I have tried iOS 8.3 and 9.1 on the iPhone) it appears that certain image files (and one sound file) get requested but never finish loading.

[Safari network panel showing images failing to load.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjnuV.png)
As you can see in the image, the files have a mixture of ones that have a status 200 (OK) and ones which don't have a status. When left, the struggling files will timeout after 11minutes.

I have tried loading the same game from desktop (windows and mac) and it launches fine every time, if I refresh on the iPhone it will load fine the second time, but clearing cache will reproduce the issue every time.

The first file to fail always seems to be the .m4a file, I can hit these files directly from the same device.

I'm at a loss as to what else I can try to get these to load successfully first time.
The site is not accessible from outside of the work network so I can't provide links.

Answer (score 0):

- can be a problem in the server .
- can be a problem with the mobile
  vision of the site.

  Try requesting `desktop site` from the iPhone .